# How to run Teraterm and TTL file using Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ttl, teraterm

From Tera Term. To start MACRO (TTL), select the [Control] Macro command and then the macro file in the Open Macro dialog box.

The question is how to write command inside batch file, to call macro file and run automatically by just opening batch file.

This is the command from previous post.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" /I /C=1 /BAUD=115200 /M=C:\Users\Public\test_ttermpro.ttl
```

From my uderstanding, /M should be command to open macro file. But now, Teraterm is open but don't execute TTL file. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution for my question. I create a batch file to execute ttpmacro.exe and .TTL file.

```
@echo on
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttpmacro.exe" "C:\PCU_BOOTLOADER.TTL"
cls
```

File location might be different. Baudrate and COM port are set inside TTL file.

Comment: can you show us the TTL file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that isn't working but maybe try:

```
 cd C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm
 TTERMPRO /I /C=1 /BAUD=115200 /M="C:\Users\Public\test_ttermpro.ttl"
```

I believe using TTERMPRO, the path to the Macro must be in quotations

---

Personally, I'd utilize the TTPMacro.exe for this function and define the connection type and baudrate within the ttl, unless there is a reason they might change between executions of the TTL.

Doing it that way, within the .ttl script add near the beginning or where applicable:

```
 connect '/C=1'
 setspeed 115200
```

That will define the com port and baud rate of the connection

---

In the batch file:

```
 cd C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm
 TTPMacro /I C:\Users\Public\test_ttermpro.ttl
```